# setting up controller for ajax post call

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

After finding and figuring out a problem in my previous code, I realized that my controller page has been blocking the call to it. I know nothing about how to code in vb, but that's what this project is based in. I'm currently searching to make sure my controller page will be set up properly to recieve the post call from my ajax function.

**JQuery Code**

```
$('#Vehicle_KovId_value').change(function () {
        var kovID = $(this).val();
        alert("Hello!");
        if (kovID != null && kovID != '') {
            $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
            $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option('Please Select One', '-1');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ProjectName/Controllers/AjaxController/Index',
                async: true,
                data: { KovID: kovID },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Please Select One", "-1");
                    alert("Worked!");
                    $.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                        $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[$('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#Vehicle_BodyStyle_value').get(0).options[0] = new Option("Error!", "-1");
                    alert("Failed to load styles");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Controller Class**

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize> _
        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function
```

I am currently recieving this error when viewing the program in Firebug:

```
The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/ProjectName/Controllers/AjaxController/Index' is not allowed.
```

I don't know anything about vb, and I haven't found any helpful pages or questions as to how I can build this controller properly so the call at least hits a breakpoint at the function. I do understand the function itself will not work right now. What I'm concerned with is the controller not accepting the call at all and therefore not even hitting the breakpoint.

Any tips or advice would be helpful, or links to pages that may assist in this. Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Just a note: If I'm slow to respond to your suggestion, I am continuing to research this question and subject as I await a reply. Once again, thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Comment: Try changing `<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize>` to `<HttpPost>` and tell me what happens.

Comment: Same error as the one I was getting before.

Comment: And if you instead use `HttpPostAttribute` (by using `<HttpPost, Authorize>`)?

Comment: Same error still. I'm wondering if I should go ahead and set the function up completely and then try it? Do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Well, it works with `GET` instead of `POST` so I'm going to try setting the function up running on that. Thank you both for your suggestions! @Douglas Barbin @Tetsujin no Oni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I had to remove `dataType: "json";` and it worked perfectly.

I also had to change `type: "POST";` to `type: "GET";` or it wasn't calling properly.